# How to display next record in database by clicking button in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make Flask application that will display in sequence title and content of articles stored in database by clicking in "Next" button but I don't know what I suppose to do below first "if" statment to fetch only one record from database. My current solutions lead to an error: `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found for one()`

Here is my code:

```
flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////PATH/TO/DATABASE/KORPUS/Database.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Polityka(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'polityka_articles'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column('article_title', db.Unicode)
    content = db.Column('article_content', db.Unicode)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def index():

    next_item = request.form.get('next_item')
    data = Database.query.filter_by(column = 'Nauka').first()

    if next_item is not None:
        data = Polityka.query.filter_by(column = 'Nauka').one()
    return render_template('home.html', item_title = data.title, item_content = data.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is `home.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tag and CSS -->
    <title>Site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>

        <h1>{{ item_title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ item_content }}</p>

    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <button type="submit" name="next_item" class="btn btn-success">Next</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be greatfull for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to pass the index to the form and then use that index for the `offset`. You probably need to add an `orderby` as well but I didn't include that here. Something like this:

```
def index():
    next_item = request.form.get('next_item')
    next_item_index = int(request.form.get('next_item_index', 0))
    data = db.query(column='Nauka').offset(next_item_index).limit(1).all()[0]
    return render_template('home.html',
        data=data,
        next_item_index=next_item_index + 1)
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{ data.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ data.content }}</p>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="next_item_index" value="{{ next_item_index }}">
    <button type="submit" name="next_item" class="btn btn-success">Next</button>
</form>
```

You'll also need to handle the case where there is no next result, as it will almost certainly cause an exception in this code.

Comment: I don't expect the syntax to work exactly as is, I was showing him the methodology so he can adapt it to his code.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this solution and I have: `
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: Yeah, there are probably exceptions in there you'll have to work out as a programmer. I just wanted to give you a general idea of the approach since you asked for a hint. Let me try to edit out that exception. (EDIT: Edited with workaround for that.)

Comment: OK. Now I understand the logic behind your solution. After this implementation I got stock with another TypeError: BaseQuery' object is not callable. I will try to solve it and will let you know if it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, it's work. I changed "Polityka.query" to ''db.session.query(Polityka)" and (as you suggest) I grouped it by id. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`one()` expects only one record will be returned otherwise it will raise the exception.

`first()` will return the first row available if not then it will return None

`all()` will return everything that you queried for

replace `one()` -> `first()` or `all()[0]`